# Evaluating a list of randomly sampled triplets with a function of three variables

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, random

I'm new to Mathematica. I need to generate a list of 1000 triplets of random numbers `{r, p, t}`, so that `0 < r < 1`, `0 < p < 2 π` and `1 < t < 10`, with `t` being an integer.

I've found the two functions `RandomReal` and ``RandomInteger`, but can't seem to obtain what I need -- namely not a list.

I need to pass this list of triplets to a function `f[r_, p_, t_]`.

Comment: `list=Transpose@{RandomReal[{0,1},1000],RandomReal[{0,2 Pi},1000], RandomInteger[{1,10},1000]}` is the most straight forward. Then you can do   `f@@@list`

Comment: From what distributions are you sampling? Do you just want uniform samples chosen? In that case, use @N.J.Evans's solution. Otherwise, please be more specific.

Comment: Regarding N.J.Evans's comment, `@@@` is shorthand for `Apply` with a *levelspec* of `{1}`; see the documentation for `Apply` for more information.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of demonstration, let us suppose

```
f[r_Real, p_Real, t_Integer] := r Sin[p t]

With[{n = 10}, 
  triples = 
    Transpose[
      {RandomReal[{0, 1}, n], 
       RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n], 
       RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n]}]];
```

Note that this last definition can generate a list of triples of any size by changing the value given to `n`.

Now, N. J. Evans' answer is the most straight forward.

```
f @@@ triples
```

> `{0.273082, 0.603514, -0.296061, 0.09708, 0.174089, -0.255095, 0.173383, 
>   0.304217, 0.170979, 0.160158}`

However, because Mathematica can apply it powerful pattern matcher to arguments, you can also do this

```
ff[{r_, p_, t_}] := f[r, p, t]
ff /@ triples
```

or even this.

```
fff[triples : {{_, _, _} ..}] := f @@@ triples
fff[triples]
```